# What express version does parse.com use for cloud code

Tags: express, parse-platform

It seems like v.3 as it does not support the Request v4 API (req.params.key vs. re.param('key')) but does anybody really know the version?

```
// let's say we call /?test=Hello

var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/', function (req, res) {

  // the express v3 way: req.param()
  res.send('Your Test-Parameter: ' + req.param('test'));

  // In express v4 you would be able to do something like this to access a GET parameter
  res.send('Your Test-Parameter: ' + req.params.test );
});
```

As far as I know the only way to find out is the package.json but it's not available in cloud code.